# Return a value from a thread in C

Tags: c, unix, pthreads, posix

I am new at threads in C using Pthreads library. I use `pthread_exit(...)` to return the value, and in `main` wait for it at the join. The thing is that, I was testing it and with two threads, the results of one of them was OK, but the other was something that do not have sense. As an example, both threads must return 32, one of them was OK, but the other returns -123456789. Someone can help me out?

```
void *contar(void *arg){  //funcion thread
int i,j=0;
int *aux = (int *) arg;
int id = *aux;
int strip = N/T;
int inicio = id*strip ;
int fin = inicio + strip;
printf("%d %d %d \n",id,inicio,fin);
for(i=inicio;i<fin;i++){
    if(VEC[i] == X){
        j++;        
    }
}

pthread_exit(&j);
}


 int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
 int i,j,k;
 void *res;
 int *aux;
 int acum=0;

  N = (argc > 1)? atoi(argv[1]):n;
  T = (argc > 2)? atoi(argv[2]):t;
  X = (argc > 3)? atoi(argv[3]):x;
  //Aloca memoria para el vetor
  VEC =(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*N);
  aux=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*T);

  //Aloca memoria para threads
  threads=(pthread_t*) malloc(T*sizeof(pthread_t));

  //Inicializa el vector VEC
  for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    VEC[i]=1;
  }   

  pthread_attr_t attr;
  pthread_attr_init (&attr);

  for(i=0;i<T;i++){
    aux[i]=i;
    pthread_create(&(threads[i]),&attr,contar,&(aux[i]));
  }   

  for(i=0;i<T;i++){
    pthread_join((threads[i]),&res);
    printf("%d \n",*(int *)res);
  } 

 free(VEC);
 free(threads);
 free(aux);
 free(res);
 return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Open Group `pthread_exit` documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_exit.html):

> After a thread has terminated, the result of access to local (auto) variables of the thread is undefined. Thus, references to local variables of the exiting thread should not be used for the pthread_exit() value_ptr parameter value.

You are returning the address of `j`, a local variable within your thread function. That's a big no-no.

As to how to fix this, there are a couple of workarounds that spring immediately to mind.

---

The first is to use global variables for the return values, one per thread. This is often used for thread IDs as well.

---

The second is to use the parameter passed *to* the thread. At the moment, you pass in an array of integers but you could easily pass in an arbitrary structure containing those integers *plus* somewhere to store the return code. The thread could then populate that part of the structure before returning.

---

Thirdly, depending on how "compatible" `int` and `void*` types are in your implementation, you could simply use the pointer itself to pass back the value. This would entail the thread doing:

```
pthread_exit ((void*)j);
```

and the mainline converting it back:

```
printf ("%d\n", (int)res);
```

---

Of those, the second is probably the "cleanest", involving neither lesser-thought-of globals nor potentially-dubious casts.

Comment: So what should I returned?

Comment: @user3420326, I've added some options on how to fix this. There may be others but this should be a good enough start at least.